# Merge hashes with same key value pair inside array

Tags: ruby

How to merge hashes within array with same key, value pair? I have following array,

```
arry = [{"id" => 1, "val1" => 123},
        {"id" => 2, "val1" => 234},
        {"id" => 1, "val2" => 321},
        {"id" => 1, "val3" => 445},
        {"id" => 3, "val3" => 334}]
```

Want to get

```
arry = [{"id" => 1, "val1" => 123, "val2" => 321, "val3" => 445},
        {"id" => 2, "val1" => 234},
        {"id" => 3, "val3" => 334}]
```

is there ruby way to do it? Tried few ways but no success so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `arry` you have posted is not a valid ruby array in the first place (I fixed it in my edit.)

```
arry.
  group_by { |h| h["id"] }.
  values.
  map { |a| a.reduce(&:merge) }
#⇒ [{"id"=>1, "val1"=>123, "val2"=>321, "val3"=>445},
#   {"id"=>2, "val1"=>234}, {"id"=>3, "val3"=>334}]
```

If your input might have same keys within the same `"id"` (like `{"id" => 1, "val1" => 123}, {"id" => 1, "val1" => 456}`,) you are to decide how to merge them. In any case, `Hash#merge` with a block would be your friend there.

Comment: If memory serves, in another recent answer you had something like `values.map { |a|..`, which you have here as well. As you well-know, you could write just `map { |_,a|...`. Do you prefer what you have for readability? (Either way, good answer.)

Comment: Exactly. Readability matters and if one has 1B of elements in the array, the issue must be fixed there.

Comment: I was just going to post `arry.group_by { |x| x['id'] }.values.map { |z| z.inject(&:merge) }` and I saw I am late.

Answer (score 1):

```
arry.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g["id"]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) } }.values
  #=> [{"id"=>1, "val1"=>123, "val2"=>321, "val3"=>445},
  #    {"id"=>2, "val1"=>234},
  #    {"id"=>3, "val3"=>334}]
```

Note the receiver of `values` is:

```
{1=>{"id"=>1, "val1"=>123, "val2"=>321, "val3"=>445},
 2=>{"id"=>2, "val1"=>234},
 3=>{"id"=>3, "val3"=>334}}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge`) that employs the block `{ |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }` to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for descriptions of the three block variables. (I've used an underscore for the first, the common key, to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.)

Comment: Appreciate such a detail answer, Thanks! Will definitely look into three block variables.

Answer (score 0):

This should work too,

```
arry.group_by { |a| a['id'] }.map{|_, ar| ar.reduce(:merge)}
```

This would return,

```
[{"id"=>1, "val1"=>123, "val2"=>321, "val3"=>445}, {"id"=>2, "val1"=>234}, {"id"=>3, "val3"=>334}]
```

Comment: This is a hair's breath different than `Aleksei`'s earlier answer. Perhaps you might have just left a comment on his answer saying that `values.` could be removed by adding the extra block variable to `map`'s block.